# I'm getting object data output from sqlite instead of the data I need

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting object data returned from my code here, but I don't see how I can be doing that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    datasource = new DataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Encouragement> values = datasource.getAllEncouragements();

    Log.d(TAG, "values");

    ArrayAdapter<Encouragement> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Encouragement>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "end of onCreate");
}
```

and

```
public List<Encouragement> getAllEncouragements() {

    List<Encouragement> encouragements = new ArrayList<Encouragement>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ENCOURAGEMENTS,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Encouragement encouragement = cursorToEncouragement(cursor);
        encouragements.add(encouragement);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return encouragements;
}
```

is producing **com.example.myActivity.myObject@34563475** in the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listview is calling `toString()` to represent myObject.  You have not overridden the `toString()` method hence the default `Object.toString()` method is called.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return this.name; // whatever you need to represent this instance of myObject.
}
```